# r - translation of dplyr to data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

How can i do the same processing with data.table? I mean, it takes lots of time in my 3,5M rows table.

Data:

```
ipoi_pdi <- tibble(
  id = c("1","1","2","3","4","4"),
  tipo_servico = c("Escala Normal", "IFR - 6 horas", "Convocação", "Escala Normal", "Convocação", "Escala Normal")
)
```

Processing:

```
ipoi_pdi %>%
  group_by(
    id
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    tipo_servico = case_when(
      n() == 1 ~ tipo_servico,
      n() > 1 & any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 6 horas") ~ "IFR - 6 horas",
      n() > 1 & any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 12 horas") ~ "IFR - 12 horas",
     TRUE ~ "Não é IFR"
    )
  ) -> ipoi_pdi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very cool package to do this kind of translation called `dtplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dtplyr)
library(data.table)
```

The only change you have to make to your original code is to wrap your object in `lazy_dt` before running the command:

```r
lazy_dt(ipoi_pdi) %>% 
  group_by(
    id
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    tipo_servico = case_when(
      n() == 1 ~ tipo_servico,
      n() > 1 & any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 6 horas") ~ "IFR - 6 horas",
      n() > 1 & any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 12 horas") ~ "IFR - 12 horas",
      TRUE ~ "Não é IFR"
    )
  ) -> ipoi_pdi
```

Now when you print the object, it displays the respective `data.table` code as `Call`:

```r
print(ipoi_pdi)
#> Source: local data table [?? x 2]
#> Call:   copy(`_DT1`)[, `:=`(tipo_servico = case_when(.N == 1 ~ tipo_servico, 
#>     .N > 1 & any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 6 horas") ~ "IFR - 6 horas", 
#>     .N > 1 & any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 12 horas") ~ "IFR - 12 horas", 
#>     TRUE ~ "Não é IFR")), keyby = .(id)]
#> 
#>   id    tipo_servico 
#>   <chr> <chr>        
#> 1 1     IFR - 6 horas
#> 2 1     IFR - 6 horas
#> 3 2     Convocação   
#> 4 3     Escala Normal
#> 5 4     Não é IFR    
#> 6 4     Não é IFR    
#> 
#> # Use as.data.table()/as.data.frame()/as_tibble() to access results
```

Transform your object to a `data.table` and run the call on it:

```r
ipoi_pdi_dt <- as.data.table(ipoi_pdi)

ipoi_pdi_dt_new <- ipoi_pdi_dt[, `:=`(tipo_servico = case_when(.N == 1 ~ tipo_servico, 
                                                               .N > 1 & any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 6 horas") ~ "IFR - 6 horas", 
                                                               .N > 1 & any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 12 horas") ~ "IFR - 12 horas", 
                                                               TRUE ~ "Não é IFR")), keyby = .(id)]

print(ipoi_pdi_dt_new)
#>    id  tipo_servico
#> 1:  1 IFR - 6 horas
#> 2:  1 IFR - 6 horas
#> 3:  2    Convocação
#> 4:  3 Escala Normal
#> 5:  4     Não é IFR
#> 6:  4     Não é IFR
```

To check if results are equal:

```r
all.equal(as.data.frame(ipoi_pdi_new), as.data.frame(ipoi_pdi_dt_new))
#> [1] TRUE
```

As `data.table` has no equivalent of `case_when`, that part stays the same. If you do this for performance reasons, that should be fine. Otherwise you have to use a bunch of `ifelse` calls to replace it.

Comment: `data.table` will soon have `fcase()`, development version already has. More info here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md. Also: avoid copying or using `copy()` when dealing with huge data like that.

Comment: Good to know! I guess they'll implement it in `dtplyr` once it's on CRAN then.

Answer (score 2):

```
setDT(ipoi_pdi)
ipoi_pdi[, 
         tipo_servico := 
           if (.N == 1) {
             tipo_servico
           } else if (any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 6 horas")) {
             "IFR - 6 horas"
           } else if (any(tipo_servico == "IFR - 12 horas")) {
             "IFR - 12 horas"
           } else {
             "Não é IFR"
           },
         by = id]
```

PS. After the first `if` we don't need to check again if `.N > 1`, we know it must be true.